# Question about the result with the presence of a comment in MySql

Tags: select, mariadb, comments

Doubt about the result with the presence of a comment in MySql

Recently  I've got an issue with a code where I've got a strange result. After some minutes, just by casualty, I could find the result. I made this simple test to check that it was not a problem with my query:

```
select
NOW()as date_1,
'4: 33.32%' as string_1, 
--- comment,
NOW() as date_2, 
--- comment
'4: 33.32%' as string_2
```

I've got this result:

[image]

By accident, I made this little change for both comments:

```
select
NOW()as date_1,
'4: 33.32%' as string_1, 
--- comment,
NOW() as date_2, 
--- comment
'4: 33.32%' as string_2, 
-- - comment,
NOW() as date_3, 
-- - comment
'4: 33.32%' as string_3
```

With this, I have the right answer:

[image]

However, I've got  doubt about the comments present before the second date and string. Why the third consecutive hyphen affected the result and what was the calculation it forced to performed.

version: 10.3.8-MariaDB

Comment: What do you mean by 'by casualty'?

Comment: I think he means "by accident" @user207421

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Barmar. Not an English speaker here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL comment begins with `--<space>`. When you write `---<space>`, the first `-` is not part of the comment, it's a minus sign *before* the comment. So it's like you wrote

```
select
NOW()as date_1,
'4: 33.32%' as string_1, 
- -- comment,
NOW() as date_2, 
- -- comment
'4: 33.32%' as string_2, 
-- - comment,
NOW() as date_3, 
-- - comment
'4: 33.32%' as string_3
```

And when you remove the comments, this is equivalent to

```
select
NOW()as date_1,
'4: 33.32%' as string_1, 
- NOW() as date_2, 
- '4: 33.32%' as string_2, 
NOW() as date_3, 
'4: 33.32%' as string_3
```

The `-` operator converts its operand to a number first, so the date in `NOW()` is converted to the number `20190621200233`, and the string `'4: 33.32%'` is converted to the number `4.000`. Then the `-` operator returns the negative of these numbers, so you see `-20190621200233` and `-4.000` in the results.